# Issue in Math functions for Lua

Tags: lua

We had given task as

Read an angle in degrees, and print the tan, cosec, sec, and cot values of that angle in the same order. To use via the rad() function, convert the angle from degrees to radians for the standard library functions.

For which we written code as

```
x = io.read()

radianVal = math.rad (x)

io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.tan(radianVal)),"\n")

io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.cosh(radianVal)),"\n")

io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.sinh(radianVal)),"\n")

io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.cos(radianVal)),"\n")
```

But output is not as expect, not sure where we went wrong

```
Run as Custom Input
30

Your Output (stdout)
0.6 
1.1 
0.5 
0.9 

Expected Output
0.57735026918963
2.0
1.1547005383793
1.7320508075689
```

Correct code which is working perfectly is

```
x = io.read()

function cot(radAngle)
  return 1 / math.tan(radAngle)
end

function cosec(radAngle)
  return 1 / math.sin(radAngle)
end

function sec(radAngle)
  return 1 / math.cos(radAngle)
end

local radAngle = math.rad(x)
print(math.tan(radAngle))
print(cosec(math.rad(x)))
print(sec(math.rad(x)))
print(cot(math.rad(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you expect to get the correct result if you calculate `cosh(x)` instead of `csc(x)`? You're using the hyperbolic cosine to calcuate the cosecant. I think it is obvious why your results are not accepted.

You use `sinh(x)` to calculate `sec(x)` and `cos(x)` to calculate `cot(x)`.

You're confusing mathematical functions. That's not a Lua programming problem.

I suggest you spend a few hours on researching trigonometric functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Such values are calcuated using the correct formula or function. Not by using any  function of the math library that has a similar name.

cosh is deprecated since Lua 5.3 btw.

You can use math.tan to calculate the tangens of your angle.

For secant, cosecant and cotangens you'll have to implement your own functions.

Also note that the number of decimals might cause issue in result validation. Make sure it is ok to round to 1 decimal.

Example:

There is no function to calculate the cotangent of an angle. So we define one.

```
function cot(radAngle)
  return 1 / math.tan(radAngle)
end

local radAngle = math.rad(30)
print("tan(30°):", math.tan(radAngle))
print("cot(30°):", cot(math.rad(30)))

->
tan(30°):   0.57735026918963
cot(30°):   1.7320508075689
```

Comment: We using now

x = io.read()

radianVal = math.rad (x)

io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.tan(radianVal)),"\n")
io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.csc(radianVal)),"\n")
io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.sec(radianVal)),"\n")
io.write(string.format("%.1f ", math.cot(radianVal)),"\n")


getting error as 

lua5.3: Solution.lua:11: attempt to call a nil value (field 'cot')
stack traceback:
 Solution.lua:11: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: I told you that you have to implement those functions yourself. there is no math.cot., no math.sec and no math.csc. hence you cannot call those functions. please read my answer, not just parts of it. also refer to the Lua manual befor you attempt to use any functions. this will tell you if those functions exist and how to use them properly.
you can  calucate all those values from the existing functions.

Comment: thanks got i but can u clarify this Read an angle in degrees, and to use via the rad() function, convert the angle from degrees to radians for the standard library functions.

Also for tan we getting out as 0.6 it sould be 0.57735026918963, how to get it

Comment: see edit. your 0.6 is caused by rounding 0.577... to 1 digit. Please get some mathematical basics right befor you start programming.

Comment: thanks issue resolved after regarding ur comments and going once again mathematical function